Screen stuck at 0 brightness after sleeping and unplugged
I am running Fedora Linux on an ASUS G14.
When my laptop goes to sleep, and then wakes up again, and then is unplugged, it will be stuck at 0 brightness. The screen will get very dim, and I will be unable to adjust the brightness.
When I run:
brightnessctl set 50%, the output is:
Updated device 'amdgpu_bl1':
Device 'amdgpu_bl1' of class 'backlight':
    Current brightness: 128 (50%)
    Max brightness: 255

but the actual brightness is still 0
When I view:
/sys/class/backlight/amdgpu_bl1/actual_brightness
the value is 0.
And then when I view:
/sys/class/backlight/amdgpu_bl1/brightness
the value is what it should be.
I can't modify any of the files in /sys/class/backlight/amdgpu_bl1/ as they are all read only.
Finally, when I change the power mode nothing changes.
When I plug my laptop back in, the brightness goes back up and is able to be adjusted as normal.
Here is my laptop and OS information:
OS: Fedora Linux 41 (Workstation Edition) x86_64
Host: ROG Zephyrus G14 GA401QM_GA401QM (1.0)
Kernel: Linux 6.12.6-200.fc41.x86_64
Uptime: 7 hours, 28 mins
Packages: 2177 (rpm), 10 (flatpak)
Shell: bash 5.2.32
Display (NCP005E): 1920x1080 @ 144 Hz (as 1536x864) in 14" [Built-in]
DE: GNOME 47.2
WM: Mutter (Wayland)
WM Theme: Adwaita
Theme: Adwaita [GTK2/3/4]
Icons: Adwaita [GTK2/3/4]
Font: Cantarell (11pt) [GTK2/3/4]
Cursor: Adwaita (24px)
Terminal: Ptyxis 47.6
Terminal Font: Source Code Pro (10pt)
 CPU: AMD Ryzen 9 5900HS (16) @ 4.68 GHz
GPU 1: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Mobile / Max-Q [Discrete]
GPU 2: AMD Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series [Integrated]
Memory: 10.32 GiB / 15.02 GiB (69%)
Swap: 1.27 GiB / 8.00 GiB (16%)
Disk (/): 18.96 GiB / 373.02 GiB (5%) - btrfs

I am also using proprietary nvidia drivers if that is relevant
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 565.77                 Driver Version: 565.77         CUDA Version: 12.7     |
|-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id          Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |           Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                        |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+========================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 ...    Off |   00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   34C    P0             21W /   80W |      13MiB /   6144MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                        |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                              |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                              GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                               Usage      |
|=========================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      2474      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                            2MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+


